# minimum maximum sum of pairs in an array

Tags: algorithm

I have a homework problem that is same as here [partition a sequence of 2n real numbers so that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817274/partition-a-sequence-of-2n-real-numbers-so-that?).

But I couldn't understand the algorithm explained in the answers.

Can anyone elaborate (with pseudocode)?

Comment: You'll get a lot out of the exercise if give it a go and try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [partition a sequence of 2n real numbers so that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817274/partition-a-sequence-of-2n-real-numbers-so-that)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm repeatedly pairs and removes the first and last elements.

I don't have much Ruby knowledge, but a quick Google search led me [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html), which revealed that `a.shift` removes and returns the first element and `a.pop` removes and returns the last.

The `# [a.first, a.last]` is just a comment (thanks [Karoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650405/karoly-horvath)).

The `<<` adds it to the array.

And the linked post already has the proof of correctness.